# Conditionally display form field in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an account (like company account) entity with a user association for the `accountOwner`.

Both account owner and users with `ROLE_ADMIN` can edit the account, but only users with `ROLE_ADMIN` can set the account owner.

Do I need 2 form types? or can I conditionally present the `accountOwner` field on the same form based on user role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can present `accountOwner` association conditionally.
When you want to modify form dynamically, you'll usually want to use [form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).

**However**, since your form's fields do not depend on actual data bound to the form, but on security context, you can just inject authorization checker into your form type and check whether you want to add needed field:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('always_present_field');
    $builder->add('another_always_present_field');

    if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $builder->add('conditional_field_if_current_user_is_admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: Confirmed. The latter approach worked great, thanks.